# Country City State List

Tags: ios, json, swift3

I have three fields that require data entry by the user. The first field is to select a country, the second field is to select a state / province and the third field is to select a city.

Is there any API  that provides the function for a user to select a country and based on that selection, then select a state and based on that selection, then select a city for the selected state?

Thanks

Comment: duplicated by :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571365/api-to-call-countries-and-states

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List of Cities by Country](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794833/list-of-cities-by-country)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Download the world-cities text file from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5QIMgUkCnHIellXemxOOGNqZjg/view)
- Data format is `City , Country , State , GeoID`

Now you can use this code below ...

```
let text = try! String(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "world-cities", ofType: "txt")!) // Reading File
let lineArray = text.components(separatedBy: "\n") // Separating Lines

        for eachLA in lineArray
        {
            let wordArray = eachLA.components(separatedBy: ",")
            // wordArray[0] is city , [1] is country and so on 
        }
```

( it was a blind and quick coding , forgive my limitations )

Comment: 2021 and this is still a next-level answer!!! Instantly have Geo Validation in my app less than 10minutes